# Raspberry pi temperature project, read on raspberry and display on remote webserver

Tags: linux, apache, nginx, ssh, raspberry-pi

I'm following [this](http://chrisbaume.wordpress.com/2013/02/10/beer-monitoring/) project that basically is a tutorial to create a local webpage and display the room temperature and humidity when you are in the local network and you access to it by going to the ip adress of the pi, there must be an apache/nginx server running.

What i want to do is use a remote webserver that i have (it's a VPS actually, so i have ssh access) for it to be acessible from anywhere, so instead of having the html and javascript and css on the pi, i'll have those on the remote server, but the pi will keep track of the temperature and create the logs, how can i send these logs every minute to the remote webserver?

Also, later, if i want to include a switch on the website to control whatever on the pi, how could i run a script on the pi, via ssh, via html frontend? (javascript? triggers ssh command to the pi and that triggers the gpio according to the script)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Most unix systems come with [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync), a remote and local file synchronization tool, installed and you can setup a [cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to run it and send the log file to the VPS at specified intervals.

So on your PI, you should be able to run

`rsync -az /PI/path/to/log.file VPS_UserName@VPS.IP.ADDR:/VPS/path/to/log.file`

Now, this would require a password each time it is run which would prevent automatic updates but you can use SSH authentication keys. This is a good guide on setting up [SSH auth keys](http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/5/15/centos-5-5-setup-part-1). Go from the part titled "SSH Keygen" to "SSH Permissions".

Comment: That sounds good... :) what about the other part? sending a signal from javascript on the webpage (hosted on the vps) to the raspberry?

Comment: The easiest way will be to just run/do whatever you want on the Pi since you control and have direct access to it. In this way, you treat the VPS like a dumb terminal only. To control the Pi from the VPS, you have a number of options such as JS/Ajax as you mentioned it all depends on how complex what you want to do is. I will suggest that you set up the dumb terminal configuration first and then extend that later and ask questions on that basis then when you have an existing set up and a clearer idea where you want to go. In other words, treat that as a Phase 2 and work on Phase 1 for now.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I've understood, your looking for a way to transfer data from `raspi` to your `VPS` by means of `ssh`.

Well one options is to use `scp` - secure copy, `scp` copies files between hosts on a network. It uses `ssh` for data transfer, and uses the same authentication and provides the same security as `ssh`

Another option is to mount your remote file system by means of `sshfs` - (Secure SHell FileSystem) is a file system for Linux capable of operating on files on a remote computer using just a secure shell login on the remote computer.

P.S. Honestly speaking the data transfers by means of `ssh` is not an elegant solution in your case.

Comment: im kind of new to linux and even more to raspberry, what do you think would be a better solution? I think that for the temperature log i could just fill a new record on a database on the remote server (although i dont know how yet), but the problem is the part of controlling the GPIO pins, i dont know of any other way really...

Comment: Make some webservice on your VPS side. Create an appropriate API for your need. Use the API to upload the temperature data to your webservice

Comment: the real problem here is that i'm not that good xD that's why i was trying to keep things simple, but how can i approach that?

Comment: you can start studying some web-programming language, the rest will come up with time. But as for now, you can go ahead with `ssh` stuff, temporarily.